# How to install openshift in RHEL 7.6 docker?

Tags: docker, openshift, atomic, rhel

I downloaded a rhel 7.6 image from the Red Hat Container Catalog. 
I followed this steps https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/install_config/install/host_preparation.html

But when I tried this command `yum install atomic-openshift-utils`, it failed with this error:

> No package atomic-openshift-utils available.

I need to install Open Shift Enterprise. How to do it in the docker ?

Answer (score 0):

To install something with yum in a RH image you'll need the container running on a rhel with valid subscription data and the correct repositories configured.

To test openshift enterprise would be better to use  rhel vms instead a docker image.

Regards.